# Load my Javascript after jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to this, but I did a lot of searching and couldn't find an answer about why my script wasn't loading after jQuery. I was receiving an error:

> $ is not defined

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li').hover(function() {
      $('ul', this).show();
    }, function() {
      $('ul', this).hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Given your example, your code is already loading after jQuery - although you're including the same jQuery library twice. One local copy, one remote. I'd strongly suggest you remove one. Did you have a specific error with the code? If so, please check the console and edit it in to the question. Also note that JS is not required for hover effects; CSS is much more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Given the error of `$ is not defined`, that means that jQuery is not included in the page properly. You most likely need to remove the second `script` tag.

Comment: Are you trying code at `file:` protocol?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hello"); //your script here
});
</script>
```

Comment: "Try this" and code only answers are discouraged. Please _explain_ how your code fixes the problem.

Comment: just deleting the second ligne :)

Answer (score 0):

[Loading JavaScript is Synchronous by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243055/how-do-browsers-handle-javascript) unless you tell the browser to handle it in a different way.
Based on that, placing your script after including jQuery will ensure your script executed after jQuery is available

So for your code to work, do something like:

```js
console.log('$ is ', typeof $)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```